# 3 queries in 1 transaction in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have this query which check first if the item is still available. If it's still available, then the server will return the item then auto decrement it.. this is my syntax, what i want to come up is i need to request only once so i need to join this 3 queries into one. is it possible? can i ask for a sample?

```
IF SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inventorylist WHERE BarcodeNumber = '9555440808279' AND NotificationQuantity > 0)
BEGIN  
   UPDATE inventorylist SET NotificationQuantity = NotificationQuantity - 1 WHERE BarcodeNumber = '9555440808279';
   SELECT * FROM inventorylist WHERE BarcodeNumber = '9555440808279';
END
```

this syntax will return an error..

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inventorylist WHERE BarcodeNumber = '95554408082' at line 1
[Err] IF SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inventorylist WHERE BarcodeNumber = '9555440808279' AND NotificationQuantity > 0)
BEGIN  
UPDATE inventorylist SET NotificationQuantity = NotificationQuantity - 1 WHERE BarcodeNumber = '9555440808279';
```

---

Comment: SQL is not a programming language :-)

Comment: you are referring to "if" that i used in the statement? i think tsql has that feature.. :)

Comment: This is not raw SQL. Are you trying to write a stored routine?

Comment: yes sql knows of IF but not in this context.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @s:=(SELECT ifnull(count(*),0) FROM inventorylist WHERE BarcodeNumber='9555440808279' and NotificationQuantity>0);
UPDATE inventorylist SET NotificationQuantity=NotificationQuantity-@s WHERE BarcodeNumber='9555440808279' and NotificationQuantity>0);
SELECT  inventorylist.*,@s AS success FROM inventorylist;
COMMIT;
```

This will allways give back your article and add a success field.

Comment: That's pretty slick, but it still runs 3 distinct queries/commands.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 It uses transaction. Transaction is faster though 3 distinct queries are used.

Comment: I guess every solution has to do that - there are three steps involved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you just care that it EXISTS then don't bother with a "SELECT *".  Just return one field:

```
IF SELECT EXISTS (SELECT BarcodeNumber FROM inventorylist WHERE BarcodeNumber = '9555440808279' AND NotificationQuantity > 0)
```

There really isn't a way (that I know of) to return the row just UPDATEd with the [UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).  So I think your best bet is to put what you've already got into a stored proc.